# How to load MathJax in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjax

I wrote an app using HTML which can render MathJax from script tag. Now I moved to React but the MathJax equation is not rendering at all.

I included a script(given below) in the `componentDidMount()`, `componentWillMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` functions, but it's not rendering.

The MathJax script is getting fetched, but it's not coming back with the script with the configuration and other fonts needed to render the equations which used to come earlier.

I also tried bringing in the MathJax React plugin(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax) too.

The code I used in the above methods:

```
(function () {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "/MathJax/MathJax.js";   // use the location of your MathJax

  var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({' +
             'extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],' +
             'jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]' +
             '});' +
             'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

  if (window.opera) {script.innerHTML = config}
           else {script.text = config}

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Earlier I used to have a simple page like

```html
<script src=<MathJax link> />
    <span>Some Equation</span>
</html>
```

Is this because of MathJax not even recognizing the content in the page?

Comment: You can also use a package to handle this I have written [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) which you can use either altogether (and just care about the math content) or to handle the downloading of MathJax (and then use `Hub` or `startup` properties (depending on version)) and do the work manually in your React component. The docs contain plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is - you need to run Mathjax parser `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);` after script loads.

Try to modify your script like this:

```
(function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "/MathJax/MathJax.js";   // use the location of your MathJax

    var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({' +
        'extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],' +
        'jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"]' +
        '});' +
        'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

    if (window.opera) {
        script.innerHTML = config
    } else {
        script.text = config
    }

    script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
    })

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Formula rendering can only happen after MathJax has loaded all needed resources and finished initialization. This is why [m51's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56187524/14952863) is not correct, as it listens to the script element's load event. At that time MathJax is not guaranteed to be initialized.

You would need to use the offical `ready` callback MathJax provides. The following example assumes you're using the current version *MathJax 3.1.x* (see [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html#performing-actions-during-initialization)). Note that the following script element needs to come before loading the MathJax library.

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready: () => {
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      // MathJax is initialized and you can trigger a typeset.
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

At that point in time MathJax typesetting is possible. But it might be necessary to delay typesetting further as there's no guarantee React has finished creating and inserting the HTML nodes.

So, you will need to account for two situations:

1. MathJax initializes first, React is not done rendering.
2. React is done rendering first, MathJax initialization still pending.

Depending on the situation you would need to have to delay the typesetting either in MathJax ready callback (Situation 1) or in a React lifecycle method (Situation 2).

There are many possible solutions to this. One could be, to use a mix of global variables and `setTimeout` to orchestrate the flow. Others involve the use of promises. But the specific solutions to this are out of scope of this answer.

I recommend using a library that abstracts away this and other problems: [react-mathjax-node](https://github.com/innodoc/react-mathjax-node)

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of *react-mathjax-node*.

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, it is possible that Mathjax is loaded and finishes typesetting before React gets the content needed to be typeset on the page. Essentially, I think, you have a race between React loading content to be typeset and Mathjax typesetting.

A simple solution is to wait till Mathjax is loaded and then set some flag in the component state that lets React know that Mathjax is loaded. Setting the state would call `componentDidUpdate` and here is where you should typeset again. Here is a little component I wrote,

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      readyToTypeset: false,
      mathjaxConfig: {
        startup: {
          ready: () => {
            window.MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
            this.setState({ readyToTypeset: true });
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.MathJax = this.state.mathjaxConfig;
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.defer = true;
    script.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.readyToTypeset)
      window.MathJax.typesetPromise();
  }
  render() {
    return String.raw`$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$`;
  }
}
```